# Python - Iterating lists and dictionaries

Tags: python, list

Hi I'm reposting this question but providing more information about what I'm trying to achieve. Its been driving me crazy for the last few days and I can't seem to make a progress. Basically, I have this data structure:

```
data_in =\
{'map': {'command_line': u'command goes here',
         'scaninfo': {u'tcp': {'method': u'syn', 'services': u'80,443'}},
         'stats': {'downhosts': u'0',
                   'elapsed': u'1.71',
                   'timestr': u'Thu Mar 20 18:18:09 2014',
                   'totalhosts': u'3',
                   'uphosts': u'3'}},
 'scan': {u'2a00:2384:0:208f::13': {'addresses': {u'ipv6': u'2a00:2384:0:f467::13',
                                                  u'mac': u'00:gf:88:9:56:D5'},
                                    'hostname': u'static.abc.com',
                                    'status': {'reason': u'nd-response',
                                               'state': u'up'},
                                    u'tcp': {80: {'conf': u'3',
                                                  'cpe': '',
                                                  'extrainfo': '',
                                                  'name': u'http',
                                                  'product': '',
                                                  'reason': u'syn-ack',
                                                  'state': u'open',
                                                  'version': ''},
                                             443: {'conf': u'3',
                                                   'cpe': '',
                                                   'extrainfo': '',
                                                   'name': u'https',
                                                   'product': '',
                                                   'reason': u'syn-ack',
                                                   'script': {u'ssl-cert': u'place holder'},
                                                   'state': u'open',
                                                   'version': ''}},
                                    'vendor': {u'00:0C:29:7C:13:D3': u'VMware'}},
          u'2a00:2384:0:208f::15': {'addresses': {u'ipv6': u'a848:2384:0:3456::15',
                                                  u'mac': u'00:gf:29:99:6D:96'},
                                    'hostname': u'static.xyz.com',
                                    'status': {'reason': u'nd-response',
                                               'state': u'up'},
                                    u'tcp': {80: {'conf': u'3',
                                                  'cpe': '',
                                                  'extrainfo': '',
                                                  'name': u'http',
                                                  'product': '',
                                                  'reason': u'syn-ack',
                                                  'state': u'open',
                                                  'version': ''},
                                             443: {'conf': u'3',
                                                   'cpe': '',
                                                   'extrainfo': '',
                                                   'name': u'https',
                                                   'product': '',
                                                   'reason': u'syn-ack',
                                                   'script': {u'ssl-cert': u'place holder'},
                                                   'state': u'open',
                                                   'version': ''}},
                                    'vendor': {u'00:0C:67:99:6f:96': u'VMware'}},
          u'2a00:2384:0:208f::16': {'addresses': {u'ipv6': u'8938:8584:0:8685::16',
                                                  u'mac': u'00:54:29:fg:55:0F'},
                                    'hostname': u'static.edf.com',
                                    'status': {'reason': u'nd-response',
                                               'state': u'up'},
                                    u'tcp': {80: {'conf': u'3',
                                                  'cpe': '',
                                                  'extrainfo': '',
                                                  'name': u'http',
                                                  'product': '',
                                                  'reason': u'syn-ack',
                                                  'state': u'open',
                                                  'version': ''},
                                             443: {'conf': u'3',
                                                   'cpe': '',
                                                   'extrainfo': '',
                                                   'name': u'https',
                                                   'product': '',
                                                   'reason': u'syn-ack',
                                                   'script': {u'ssl-cert': u'place holder'},
                                                   'state': u'open',
                                                   'version': ''}},
                                    'vendor': {u'00:0C:55:AE:33:ff': u'VMware'}}}}
```

And need to create a simplified version of it that looks like this:

```
data_out =\
[{'address': u'2a00:2384:0:208f::13',
  'hostname': u'static.bt.com',
  'ports': [{80: {'reason': u'syn-ack', 'state': u'open'}},
            {443: {'reason': u'syn-ack',
                   'ssl_cert': u'place   holder',
                   'state': u'open'}}]}]
```

As per previous advice from @jonrsharpe I've created a helper function that enables me to find keys. This has proved helpful, but I still struggling to get the desired results.

```
def find_key(data, search_key, out=None):
"""Find all values from a nested dictionary for a given key."""
if out is None:
    out = []
if isinstance(data, dict):
    if search_key in data:
        out.append(data[search_key])
    for key in data:
        find_key(data[key], search_key, out)
return out
```

Any help would be really appreciated here!

Comment: Obviously, the answer you accepted in the previous question didn’t turn out to be that helpful after all. So why don’t you go back and look at the other answers which focused more on navigating your actual structure (instead of randomly finding keys *anywhere*) and try to come up with something on your own?

Comment: I think your data-out is badly formatted. You have commas in place of colons. Should be: `data_out = [{'address': u'2a00:2384:0:208f::13', 
             'hostname': u'static.bt.com', 
             'ports': [{80: {'state': u'open', 'reason': u'syn-ack'}}, 
                       {443: {'ssl_cert': u'place   holder', 'state': u'open', 'reason': u'syn-ack'}}]
            }]`

Comment: Yep - Sorry fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't all that hard; you just have to go through and look at the data structure that leads to what you want - which is made much harder by poor formatting, so I re-indented your input and marked the keys (`<==`) and fields (`!!!`) you are seeking:

```
data_in = {
    'map': {
        'stats': {
            'uphosts': u'3',
            'timestr': u'Thu Mar 20 18:18:09 2014',
            'downhosts': u'0',
            'totalhosts': u'3',
            'elapsed': u'1.71'
        },
        'scaninfo': {
            u'tcp': {
                'services': u'80,443',
                'method': u'syn'
            }
        },
        'command_line': u'command goes here'
    },
    'scan': {                           # <==
        u'2a00:2384:0:208f::13': {          # <== !!!
            'status': {
                'state': u'up',
                'reason': u'nd-response'
            },
            'hostname': u'static.abc.com',      # !!!
            'vendor': {
                u'00:0C:29:7C:13:D3': u'VMware'
            },
            'addresses': {
                u'mac': u'00:gf:88:9:56:D5',
                u'ipv6': u'2a00:2384:0:f467::13'
            },
            u'tcp': {                       # <==
                80: {                       # <== !!!
                    'product': '',
                    'state': u'open',           # !!!
                    'version': '',
                    'name': u'http',
                    'conf': u'3',
                    'extrainfo': '',
                    'reason': u'syn-ack',       # !!!
                    'cpe': ''
                },
                443: {                      # <== !!!
                    'product': '',
                    'state': u'open',           # !!!
                    'version': '',
                    'name': u'https',
                    'conf': u'3',
                    'script': {             # <==
                        u'ssl-cert': u'place holder'  # !!!
                    },
                    'extrainfo': '',
                    'reason': u'syn-ack',       # !!!
                    'cpe': ''
                }
            }
        },
        u'2a00:2384:0:208f::15': {
            'status': {
                'state': u'up',
                'reason': u'nd-response'
            },
            'hostname': u'static.xyz.com',
            'vendor': {
                u'00:0C:67:99:6f:96': u'VMware'
            },
            'addresses': {
                u'mac': u'00:gf:29:99:6D:96',
                u'ipv6': u'a848:2384:0:3456::15'
            },
            u'tcp': {
                80: {
                    'product': '',
                    'state': u'open',
                    'version': '',
                    'name': u'http',
                    'conf': u'3',
                    'extrainfo': '',
                    'reason': u'syn-ack',
                    'cpe': ''
                },
                443: {
                    'product': '',
                    'state': u'open',
                    'version': '',
                    'name': u'https',
                    'conf': u'3',
                    'script': {
                        u'ssl-cert': u'place holder'
                    },
                    'extrainfo': '',
                    'reason': u'syn-ack',
                    'cpe': ''
                }
            }
        },
        u'2a00:2384:0:208f::16': {
            'status': {
                'state': u'up',
                'reason': u'nd-response'
            },
            'hostname': u'static.edf.com',
            'vendor': {
                u'00:0C:55:AE:33:ff': u'VMware'
            },
            'addresses': {
                u'mac': u'00:54:29:fg:55:0F',
                u'ipv6': u'8938:8584:0:8685::16'
            },
            u'tcp': {
                80: {
                    'product': '',
                    'state': u'open',
                    'version': '',
                    'name': u'http',
                    'conf': u'3',
                    'extrainfo': '',
                    'reason': u'syn-ack',
                    'cpe': ''
                },
                443: {
                    'product': '',
                    'state': u'open',
                    'version': '',
                    'name': u'https',
                    'conf': u'3',
                    'script': {
                        u'ssl-cert': u'place holder'
                    },
                    'extrainfo': '',
                    'reason': u'syn-ack',
                    'cpe': ''
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and likewise for your desired output (with appropriate adjustments):

```
data_out = [
    {
        'address': u'2a00:2384:0:208f::13',
        'hostname': u'static.bt.com',
        'ports': {
            80: {
                'state': u'open',
                'reason': u'syn-ack'
            },
            443: {
                'ssl_cert': u'place   holder',
                'state': u'open',
                'reason': u'syn-ack'
            }
        }
    }
]
```

then the extraction becomes:

```
def remap_port(port, port_data):
    result = {
        "state":  port_data["state"],
        "reason": port_data["reason"]
    }
    try:
        result["ssl_cert"] = port_data["script"]["ssl-cert"]
    except KeyError:
        pass
    return port, result

def remap_scanned_address(address, address_data):
    return {
        "address":  address,
        "hostname": address_data["hostname"],
        "ports":    dict(remap_port(port, port_data) for port,port_data in address_data["tcp"].items())
    }

def remap_scan_data(data_in):
    return [remap_scanned_address(address, address_data) for address, address_data in data_in["scan"].items()]

data_out = remap_scan_data(data_in)
```

which results in the desired output,

```
[{'address': u'2a00:2384:0:208f::13',
  'hostname': u'static.abc.com',
  'ports': {80: {'reason': u'syn-ack', 'state': u'open'},
            443: {'reason': u'syn-ack',
                  'ssl_cert': u'place holder',
                  'state': u'open'}}},
 {'address': u'2a00:2384:0:208f::15',
  'hostname': u'static.xyz.com',
  'ports': {80: {'reason': u'syn-ack', 'state': u'open'},
            443: {'reason': u'syn-ack',
                  'ssl_cert': u'place holder',
                  'state': u'open'}}},
 {'address': u'2a00:2384:0:208f::16',
  'hostname': u'static.edf.com',
  'ports': {80: {'reason': u'syn-ack', 'state': u'open'},
            443: {'reason': u'syn-ack',
                  'ssl_cert': u'place holder',
                  'state': u'open'}}}]
```

Comment: Thank you so much -Think I spent so long staring at it I couldn't see the trees and hit a bit of a wall. As you say made harder by poor formatting. I will study in detail your example. Thanks again.